# Is Expression blend sufficient for windows 8 Mobile app development

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-mobile, expression-blend

I'm a beginner in Windows 8 App development and I know that we can develop app using C# + XAML and My question is - Expression blend alone is sufficient to develop the mobile app or we need VS 2012 along with it ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Blend is used for UI & UI related effects. VS is definately needed. You can develop in VS without blend after some practice :)